# Why does output say Invalid ESP-IDF when I follow recommended official installation instructions to the letter?

Tags: espressif-idf

I followed the recommeded installation instructions of the official ESP-IDF in Visual Studio Code for Windows and after downloading and installing through the Visual Studio Code ESP-IDF extension, the output is Invalid ESP-IDF.

I tried to install ESP-IDF and I expected it to work and then this official installation said Invalid ESP-IDF.

Comment: did you try the express or the advance installation? I had the same issue and the problem was the version of Python and the dependencies for that.